# Trigger an Azure DevOps pipeline with a comment when a path filter is defined

Tags: azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that runs our full test suite. It is slow, so we only want to run it on pull requests when the tests are changed or a test run is explicitly requested with a GitHub comment. I have tried the following configuration below.

```yaml
pr:
  paths:
    include:
      - tests/integration/*
```

The problem that I am experiencing is that commenting on the pull request with `/azp run tests` does not work when path filters are used. The bot replies back with "Azure Pipelines could not run because the pipeline triggers exclude this branch/path."

Does anyone know if what I am trying to accomplish is possible, and how to configure it?

I understand that I could create multiple pipelines with different triggers, but I am hoping to get this to work with a single pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your steps, I can reproduce the followig issue.
[image]

After reviewing this doc: [Comment triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#comment-triggers), we can see the following prerequisites.
[image]
Testing this we find that only pushes to branches that are explicitly configured to be included on **Pull request validation** will trigger a pipeline using comment like `/azp run test`, as below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Drat that's too bad. Thank you for confirming!

Comment: Using the same approach and GitHub comment, it possible to trigger any other pipeline which may not be associated with this particular repository?